# Is it possible for String.split() to return a null node in the resulting array?

Tags: java, string, split

Is there any string out there that could return an array with a null node when .split is called? Here's what I tried:

```
    String string = "test,,test";
    if (string != null && !string.isEmpty()) {
        String[] parsedString = string.split(",");
        for (String stringNode : parsedString) {
            if (stringNode != null) {
                //perform logic here. Omitted for the purpose of this question.
            }
        }
    }
```

I want my method to be able handle a null string, but if String.split() can't return an array with a null node, then it is probably safe to remove right?

Comment: Luke, use the source. http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html#2311

Comment: split doesn't return `null`, nor will it return an array which contains `null`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, String.split(String regex) can never return an array with a `null` element in it.

There are only three cases to account for:

1. `regex` is invalid, a `PatternSyntaxException` is thrown
2. `regex` isn't found, the array will only contain the original string.
3. `regex` is found, the string is split.

Answer (score 4):

Look at [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)

split( ) method.

```
String str = "1,2,3,,4";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split(",")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(StringUtils.split(str,",")));
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, , 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Is this what you expect?

Hope this helps...

Comment: I think this is better: public static String[] splitPreserveAllTokens(final String str, final String separatorChars)

Comment: sepratorChars doesn't work as expected when you want to split a string by multiple character delimiter

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove `if (stringNode != null)`.
A null value will not be returned. An empty string might be returned by `String.split()` (as an array element, I mean).

Answer (score -1):

As per the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), neither null nor empty strings will be returned by String.split().